# Jquery tooltip problem (flowplayer toolitp)

Tags: jquery, tooltip, flowplayer

When page is loaded first, tooltip comes fine but for every other postback it throws error that (".download_now").tooltip({effect: 'slide',delay:300).dynamic is not a function.

There is no issue with asp.net ajax since updatepanel postback is always.

Here is the js:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(MainEndRequestHandler);

            $(MainEndRequestHandler);

            function MainEndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                loadeverthingmaster();
            }

            function loadeverthingmaster(){
                 try
                 {  

                          $(".download_now").tooltip({ 
                              effect: 'slide',
                              delay:300


                          }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });          


                       $(".help-bubble-link[title]").tooltip({

                          // tweak the position
                          offset: [10, 2],

                          // use the "slide" effect
                          effect: 'slide',

                          // add dynamic plugin with optional configuration for bottom edge
                       }).dynamic({ bottom: { direction: 'down', bounce: true } });

                 }
                 catch(err)
                 {
                     //alert(err);
                 } 
            }
```

Tooltip html :

```
<a class="download_now">?</a>
<div class="tooltip" style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: -6px; left: 170.5px; display: none; opacity: 0;">
   <div style="display:block;" id="divTooltipLabelAreaf49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c">
      <span id="spanEditf49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c" class="tooltip-message-span no-content">
           No notes
      </span>

      <br>
      <a onclick="StartEditTooltip('f49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c')" href="#">Edit</a>
   </div>
   <div style="display:none;" id="divEditAreaf49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c">
      <textarea id="inputTextf49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c">           
      </textarea> 
      <br>
      <a onclick="CancelEditTooltip('f49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c')" href="#">Cancel</a>
      <a onclick="SaveEditTooltip('f49db1de-11ce-4667-bd7d-f655dec1435c','/Query/Ascx/QueryAutoCompleteService.asmx/SaveQueryNotes','51')" href="#">Save</a>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution, since I have the same problem?